# How do I suppress the output of namespaces with XML serialization?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have serialized an object using XmlSerializer and am receiving unwanted namespace attributes in my output. How can I prevent it from printing these namespaces in the XML?

```
// write and close the bar
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof( DecisionBar));

serializer.Serialize(writer, decision);

public class DecisionBar
{
    public DateTime bartime { get; set; }
    public string frequency { get; set; }
    public bool HH7 { get; set; }
    public bool crossover { get; set; }
    public double mfe { get; set; }
    public double mae { get; set; }
    public double entryPointLong { get; set; }
    public double entryPointShort { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```xml
<DecisionBar xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <bartime>2012-07-23T07:22:00</bartime>
  <frequency>1 MINUTES</frequency>
  <HH7>true</HH7>
  <crossover>false</crossover>
  <mfe>0</mfe>
  <mae>0</mae>
  <entryPointLong>1.2139</entryPointLong>
  <entryPointShort>1.212</entryPointShort>
</DecisionBar>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
serializer.Serialize(writer, decision, ns);
```

Comment: In addition, `var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new [] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });` if one-liners excite you.

Comment: @marc that's quite cute ; I can't say that I'd noticed XmlQualifiedName.Empty before.

Comment: how do i get rid of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> that comes there?

Comment: @junkone XmlWriterSettings, OmitXmlDeclaration - use it when creating the XmlWriter